# Dragged component does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/f5vGQ/

1. DragDiv contains a kendo numeric textbox.
2. DragDiv can be dropped on DropDiv.
3. When DragDiv is dropped the DropDiv conatains the same kendo numeric textbox.

Now, in DragDiv the spin event of kendo text box works properly. But when the dragging is complete (in the DropDiv) it doesn't. Where is it wrong?

Comment: Could be to do with the fact that when you duplicate the textbox, the Id is also duplicated. IDs should be unique within a document and never duplicated. But on further inspection (changing the ID to a class) it appears not to be the error. http://jsfiddle.net/f5vGQ/1/

Comment: yes, id or class is not a problem. Actually the dragged component is a copy of the html text. There must be some way to initialize or de-initialize numeric box.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're copying the HTML of the kendo processed element. You just need to append the base HTML, i.e., the input. 
`.append('<input type="text" class="nt" />');`

and then you need to call the kendo again. Also, as Kyle Sevenoaks suggested, use a class.

I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f5vGQ/5/